# Microsoft Botframwork publishing ping error

Tags: node.js, bots, ping, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to publish my bot, but have an issue.
When I hit "Submit for Review" button it shows me this error

> Your bot did not respond to our Ping request with a success code.
>   Please verify your bot is running and responsive before Publishing
>   your bot. The error received from your bot was: Forbidden(403),
>   Forbidden

I checked my server logs and saw this error from `botbuilder` package of NPM

> ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - endorsements validation failure.
>   channelId in req.body: test didn't match the endorsements:
>   bing,directline,email,facebook,groupme,kik,skype,slack,sms,telegram,webchat.

And this is ping request from Microsoft

```
{ type: 'ping',
  id: '6rQ0LAG7X2Q',
  timestamp: '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  serviceUrl: 'https://dev.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'test',
  from: { id: 'portal' },
  conversation: { id: 'ping' },
  recipient: { id: 'bot' } }
```

Basically `ChatConnector` dont' accept requests with channelId `test`, so how can I publish my app?

Comment: Maybe you should [open an issue for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues)?

Comment: We are actively investigating the issue.

Comment: There's a problem with the publishing workflow. We are actively working to fix the issue.

Comment: Fix has been deployed.